# Cannot create an instance of an abstract class (Random)

Tags: random, kotlin

I am trying to learn Kotlin so I was following a tutorial on internet where instructor wrote a code which worked fine in with them but it gives error to me.

This is the error

> Error:(26, 17) Kotlin: Cannot create an instance of an abstract class

```
import kotlin.random.Random

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    feedTheFish()
}

fun feedTheFish() {
    val day = randomDay()
    val food = "pellets"
    print("Today is ${day} and the fish eat ${food}")
}


fun randomDay():String {
    val week = listOf ("Monday", "Tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday")
    return week[ Random().nextInt(7)]
}
```

I am getting error from return statement, I think from Random. Please help me to understand this and fix this code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just remove the parentheses: `Random.nextInt(7)`.

Like this it uses the companion object (`Default`) of class `Random` which implements the abstract class `Random` with a default behaviour.

From the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.random/-random/index.html):

> The companion object Random.Default is the default instance of Random

Answer (score 0):

It happened because you are trying to invoke function of abstract class, but abstract class have no instance. Instead you can use static function from Random companion object

```
Random.nextInt(yourIntValue)
```